# How to get all data-id and amount from html page using jQuery and post it via ajax with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

How can i get all **data-id** and **amount** from this HTML page using jquery. After getting those value... I want to push it to array then post via ajax. This is a laravel project. I am not using **Form** here.

[This is that image, from where I want to get value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8rQ.png)

```
//Here is the Html code
       <?php $i=1 ?>
        @foreach($expanse as $expanse)
           <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{$i}}</td>
                <td>
                  <h4 class="expVal" data-id="{{$expanse->id}}">{{$expanse->name}}</h4>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                     <a href="#" class="expanseRent" data-type="text" data-placement="right" id="rent[]" data-title="Enter rent">{{$expanse->rent}}</a>
                 </td>

          </tr>
         <?php $i++ ?>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: So, which element will be having the data-id?only `h4`?

Comment: I am using foreach loop.. So, every data is showing this table. I want all data-id .. this one data-id="{{$expanse->id}}" 

You can check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8rQ.png

Comment: I mean data-id will be available in h4 tag right?

Comment: give my answer a try and let me know in case you face any problem.

Comment: please accept any of the answer which solved your problem to close this question and upvote any/all answer that has helped to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data Ids and amount like this

```
var ids = [],amounts = [];
$(".expVal").each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).data('id'));
    var b = $(this).parent().next().find('a.expanseRent').text();
    amounts.push(b);
})
```

Another method would be

```
var datas=[];
    $(".expVal").each(function(){

        var a = $(this).data('id');
        var b = $(this).parent().next().find('a.expanseRent').text();

        datas.push(a+":"+b);
    })
```

Comment: Actually, i want like this 
[data-id:rent,data-id:rent,...]
i.e: [1:9200,2:1200,....]

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the each `.expVal` elements in jquery and then you can get the `data-id` attribute using jquery.

After that, you can push this values into some array.

```
var data_id_array=[];

$( ".expVal" ).each(function( index ) {
  data_id_array.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

For rent, add rent in `data-rent` attribute like this.

```
<a href="#" class="expanseRent" data-rent="{{$expanse->rent}}" data-type="text" data-placement="right" id="rent[]" data-title="Enter rent">{{$expanse->rent}}</a>
```

then, do same process like this to get rent.

```
    var rent_array=[];

    $( ".expanseRent" ).each(function( index ) {
      rent_array.push($(this).attr('data-rent'));
    });
```

So, for your output,as you mentioned in comment,loop through the `data_id_array` array and create json item like you want and push it into the `finalArray` like this.

```
var finalArray = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data_id_array.length; ++i) {
    var itemArr={};
    itemArr[data_id_array[i]] =  rent_array[i];
    finalArray.push(itemArr);
}
```

So at the end, `finalArray` will contain all the items like `[{1:1200},{2:3000}]` like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data-* using jquery's [data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) like this

```
$(".expVal").data("id")
```

*assuming you have `.expVal` class in each `<td>`.

```
var attrs = [];
var vals = [];
$(".expVal").each(function(){
    attrs.push($(this).attributes.nodeName);
    vals.push($(this).data("id")+":"+$(this).data("rent"));
})
```

Then pass it into your `ajax` `POST` call like this

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "url",
      data: dataIDs
});
```

Comment: Actually, i want like this [data-id:rent,data-id:rent,...] i.e: [1:9200,2:1200,....]

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query like, which will return you an object indexed in the order of occurrence of the element in the DOM.
`$("[data-id]")`

Additionally i would also include the amount as a data attribute in the same element, something like 
`<h4 class="expVal" data-id="{{$expanse->id}}" data-amount="{{$expanse->rent}}">{{$expanse->name}}</h4>`
and now through dataset property you will be able to access,
`$("[data-id]")[0].dataset.amount`
here is the documentation on the data attribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes